# Creating a Series of Repeating Pulses for Medical Alarms

Tags: harmonics

I need to implement an audio alarm mp3/wav clip that contains a series of repeating pulses, where each pulse has to  have a **fundamental frequency somewhere between 150 to 1000 Hz, and there must be at least four harmonic sounds from 300 to 4000 Hz.**

My question is : would it be possible for me to create such an audio file from whatever libraries in python/matlab/c or musical programming softwares? I found out a Max patcher(https://music.arts.uci.edu/dobrian/maxcookbook/generate-burst-audio-pulses) that creates 25 bursts of pulses.  However it obviously doesn't satisfy the requirement mentioned above.
Could anyone give some direction? Thank you!

-Yumeka

Comment: What did you attempt ? What is your current knowledge in audio processing and programming languages ?

Comment: @audionuma thanks for your comment! i have no experience in audio processing, but am familiar with python/matlab in terms of programming. I have tried to use some online tone generator to create the required alarm audio to no avail. Now I am interested in trying out a musical software called Max. Would like to know what are some "easier" ways to implement/create the audio:)

Comment: Are you willing to do this manually thru a digital audio workstation or is the programming aspect required ? Because you can easily produce such files with any decent audio editor by manually creating tone tracks and summing them.